# Handlebars helper to return image height (width * ratio) returns NaN

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, helper

I am using Handlebarz to load pictures with some text. I need to be able to specify the height of each image in order for the images to not overlap when they are drawn on the screen.

I have registered a helper function as so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    Handlebars.registerHelper("height", function(width,ratio) {
        var h = width * ratio;
        return h;
    })
   ...
})
```

I am trying to use the helper as so `style="height: {{height 158 product.image1.ratio}}1

The variable product.image1.ratio displays values when used on its own, however this syntax doesn't call the helper properly as the result is always NaN.

Comment: Are you sure that `product.image1.ratio` has a value? The code should work fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/v8W6p/) unless `ratio` is `undefined`.

Comment: I'll do another check. I've printed it out eleshwere and it looks ok.

Comment: I have some values of ratio that are 0, perhaps that is affecting the rest. If the syntax should work, then at least I know the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: A zero `ratio` is fine, `undefined` or `NaN` not so fine. If you're getting a `NaN` out then you must be getting `undefined` or `NaN` as a `ratio` value; I'd suspect `undefined` given the `product.image1.ratio` expression.